# What is the best way to build UIs for Python Applications?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

I would like to know what you suggest as a framework to build UIs for Python applications.
I heard of Qt as a good solution. Is it suggested to learn Qt? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is built into Python; it's not quite as pretty as Qt, but its ubiquity is worth a lot.

Comment: Okay. Do you know any reading on tkinter?

Comment: @user3227418 We use search engines, and they can be quite empowering. You can know as much as we do, in just a few keystrokes. In other words: it's somewhat counterproductive to ask such a question before typing the keyword into google first. It takes just as much time, but you get instant answers :)

Comment: I hoped that somebody here had specific suggestions because there is such a variety of books out there from which it is difficult to choose...

Comment: @user3227418: `import Tkinter` / `help(Tkinter)`; also, http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Tkinter

Comment: Okay. I'll read through this, Thanks for your help!